# The wrap around checkbox is missing in the search dialog in Notepad++ v 6.1.6. How do I toggle that setting?

Tags: notepad++

The wrap around checkbox is missing in the search dialog in Notepad++ v 6.1.6. How do I toggle that setting?

Upgrading to the latest version is not an option for me as I don't have the rights to install applications on the computer myself.

Comment: The "Find" window has four tabs (Find, Replace, Find in files and Mark. The window title shows the selected tab) and there is a "Wrap_around" tick box in all except the "Find in files" wih Notepad++ 6.6.8. I believe the tick box as been there in all Notepad++ 6.* versions. Check also the `<FindHistory... wrap="..."` entry in the `config.xml` file - in `C:\Users\xxx\AdrianHHH\Roaming\Notepad++\` for me.

Comment: It is strange. The reason I asked in the fist place is because wrap around is active on my computer but inactive on my coworkers computer and it is a problem for her. I don't have that checkbox at all and neither does she. We have the same version of Notepad++.

Comment: Whoops, the directory should have been `C:\Users\AdrianHHH\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\`.

Comment: It works. My coworker's wrap entry was "no". She changed it to "yes" and now it works. Write it as an answer instead of as a comment and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know why the toggle is missing, but its value held in the `config.xml` file, look for the section with

```
<FindHistory... wrap="..."
```

The `config.xml` file can be in any of several places depending on operating system version and user preference. In my case the file is in `C:\Users\AdrianHHH\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`.

Normally the "Find" window has four tabs (**Find**, **Replace**, **Find in files** and **Mark**. The window title shows the selected tab) and there is a "**Wrap_around**" tick box in all except the "**Find in files**" tab (checked in Notepad++ 6.6.8). I believe the tick box as been there in all Notepad++ 6.* versions

Comment: Make sure you don't have Notepad++ open while you edit the config.xml.